# Put property file into a jar file using ProcessBuilder

Tags: jar, processbuilder

I need to put a property file named "customer.properties" into the "distribution.jar". Fle paths for above files are;

- modules\distribution.jar
- modules\distributionaManager\customer.properties

My requirement is to have "modules\distribution.ja\distributionaManager\customer.properties"

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("jar", "uf", "distribution.jar", "distributionaManager\\customer.properties");
        pb.directory(jarFile.getParentFile());
        try
        {
            Process process = pb.start();
            process.waitFor();
            process.destroy();
        }
```

jarFile.getParentFile() - "modules directory"

But this code creates no property file inside the jar. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Try not to use an external process and use Java code to manipulate the jar files.

Comment: This jar file is something already created and I just want to add a property file to it before handing over to the customer. I guess this is the easiest way of doing it. Using a batch file, I already run the same command and get the work done. But i don't like to use an external batch file and need to implement this in java itself.